# Data being copied to other dynamic tables in HTML form

Tags: javascript, php, html, dynamic, html-table

I am having trouble with the way my data is being displayed. Any data that is entered into the first and second tables will not be displayed, but anything entered into the 3rd table will be displayed in not only the 3rd table, but the first and second as well. How can I change this so the data can be displayed in each table separately.

Here is an example of what it looks like:
[image: Data Entered]

[image: Data displayed]

Here is my HTML/PHP related code:

```
<p>
<div class="border1">
<div id="rebate_400p">
<strong>400P</strong><br>
</div>

<?php if(isset($_POST['rows'])): ?>
    <table cellspacing="20">
        <tr align="center" class="table_row">
            <td>Tier</td>
            <td>Purchase Minimum</td>
            <td>Multiplier</td>
            <td>UOM</td>
            <td>Retro</td>
            <td>Guaranteed</td>
            <td>Paid</td>
        </tr>
        <?php 
            $count = 1;
            foreach($_POST['rows'] as $row): 
        ?>
            <tr align="center">
                <td><?php echo $count; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['purchase_minimum']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['multiplier']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['uom']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['retro']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['guaranteed']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['paid']; ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php 
            $count++;
            endforeach; 
        ?>
    </table>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
</p>

<!-- 400M -->
<p>
<div class="border1">
<div id="rebate_400m">
<strong>400M</strong><br>
</div>

<?php if(isset($_POST['rows'])): ?>
    <table cellspacing="20">
        <tr align="center" class="table_row">
            <td>Tier</td>
            <td>Purchase Minimum</td>
            <td>Multiplier</td>
            <td>UOM</td>
            <td>Retro</td>
            <td>Guaranteed</td>
            <td>Paid</td>
        </tr>
        <?php 
            $count = 1;
            foreach($_POST['rows'] as $row): 
        ?>
            <tr align="center">
                <td><?php echo $count; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['purchase_minimum']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['multiplier']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['uom']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['retro']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['guaranteed']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['paid']; ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php 
            $count++;
            endforeach; 
        ?>
    </table>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
</p>

<!-- 400D -->
<p>
<div class="border1">
<div id="rebate_400d">
<strong>400D</strong><br>
</div>

<?php if(isset($_POST['rows'])): ?>
    <table cellspacing="20">
        <tr align="center" class="table_row">
            <td>Tier</td>
            <td>Purchase Minimum</td>
            <td>Multiplier</td>
            <td>UOM</td>
            <td>Retro</td>
            <td>Guaranteed</td>
            <td>Paid</td>
        </tr>
        <?php 
            $count = 1;
            foreach($_POST['rows'] as $row): 
        ?>
            <tr align="center">
                <td><?php echo $count; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['purchase_minimum']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['multiplier']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['uom']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['retro']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['guaranteed']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['paid']; ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php 
            $count++;
            endforeach; 
        ?>
    </table>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
</p>
```

Here is some of my Javascript code:

```
// ----- Deletes row for 400p -----
function deleteRow(row)
{
    var i=row.parentNode.parentNode;
    i.parentNode.removeChild(i);
}

// ----- Adds row for 400p -----
function insRow()
{
  var x=document.getElementById('tables');
  var new_row = x.rows[1].cloneNode(true);
  var len = x.rows.length;
  new_row.cells[0].innerHTML = len;

  var inp1 = new_row.cells[1].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
  inp1.id += len;
  inp1.value = '';
  var inp2 = new_row.cells[2].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
  inp2.id += len;
  inp2.value = '';

  var inputs = new_row.querySelectorAll('input[type=text]');

  for(var i=0;i<inputs.length;i++)
  {
      inputs[i].value='';
      inputs[i].name='rows[' + len + '][' + inputs[i].dataset.name + ']';
  }

  x.appendChild(new_row)
}

// ----- JS for 400M -----

// ----- Deletes row for 400m -----
function deleteRow1(row)
{
    var i=row.parentNode.parentNode;
    i.parentNode.removeChild(i);
}

// ----- Adds row for 400m -----
function insRow1()
{
  var x=document.getElementById('tables1');
  var new_row1 = x.rows[1].cloneNode(true);
  var len = x.rows.length;
  new_row1.cells[0].innerHTML = len;

  var inp1 = new_row1.cells[1].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
  inp1.id += len;
  inp1.value = '';
  var inp2 = new_row1.cells[2].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
  inp2.id += len;
  inp2.value = '';

  var inputs = new_row1.querySelectorAll('input[type=text]');

  for(var i=0;i<inputs.length;i++)
  {
      inputs[i].value='';
      inputs[i].name='rows[' + len + '][' + inputs[i].dataset.name + ']';
  }

  x.appendChild(new_row1)
}

// ----- JS for 400D -----

// ----- Deletes row for 400d -----
function deleteRow2(row)
{
    var i=row.parentNode.parentNode;
    i.parentNode.removeChild(i);
}

// ----- Adds row to 400d -----
function insRow2()
{
  var x=document.getElementById('tables2');
  var new_row2 = x.rows[1].cloneNode(true);
  var len = x.rows.length;
  new_row2.cells[0].innerHTML = len;

  var inp1 = new_row2.cells[1].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
  inp1.id += len;
  inp1.value = '';
  var inp2 = new_row2.cells[2].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
  inp2.id += len;
  inp2.value = '';

  var inputs = new_row2.querySelectorAll('input[type=text]');

  for(var i=0;i<inputs.length;i++)
  {
      inputs[i].value='';
      inputs[i].name='rows[' + len + '][' + inputs[i].dataset.name + ']';
  }

  x.appendChild(new_row2)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved your issue by modifying your code in several different places. In your current code, you get chaotic results because you're overwriting some values by using same array index. In order to make sure it does not conflict, I would suggest to use [multidimensional arrays](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays_multi.asp). A few changes:

**1.** First table contains multiple indexes:

*Added an additional `[0]` index. This should apply to all inputs, not just `purchase_minimum`*

```
<input type="text" id="rebate_tables" data-name="purchase_minimum" name="rows[0][0][purchase_minimum]">
```

In second table we do the same but write `[1]` instead of `[0]` as in the first table (next index with increasing order):

```
<input type="text" id="rebate_tables" data-name="purchase_minimum" name="rows[1][0][purchase_minimum]">
```

And in the third table we will have `[2]`:

```
<input type="text" id="rebate_tables" data-name="purchase_minimum" name="rows[2][0][purchase_minimum]">
```

Also, it's important to make last indexes (words) without a number (instead of `purchase_minimum1` like in your case, use `purchase_minimum`).

**2.** In JavaScript we do the same thing + second index should be `len - 1` instead of `len` because otherwise would go 0, 2, 3, 4, ...

*For 1st table:*

```
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    inputs[i].value = '';
    inputs[i].name = 'rows[0][' + (len - 1) + '][' + inputs[i].dataset.name + ']';
}
```

For 2nd table we will have:

```
inputs[i].name = 'rows[1][' + (len - 1) + '][' + inputs[i].dataset.name + ']';
```

And in the third:

```
inputs[i].name = 'rows[2][' + (len - 1) + '][' + inputs[i].dataset.name + ']';
```

**3.** In your confirmation page we change only `foreach` in all areas:

*Would be:*

```
foreach($_POST['rows'][0] as $row):
```

*Instead of:*

```
foreach($_POST['rows'] as $row):
```

Also, in each `foreach` you'll have to remove those same additional numbers in (string) indexes, like:

```
<td><?php echo $row['purchase_minimum']; ?></td>
```

*Let me know if I missed anything and it's still not working.*

Comment: Works perfectly!!

Answer (score 2):

I figured out my problem. In my php code, for each table, I had the same name for each text box that I entered data. I changed the names for each one and that fixed the problem.

Comment: I have a new problem now that you may be able to fix...It displays different info in each table but for example, if i put 2 rows in the middle table and only 1 row of data in the 1st and 3rd table, then in the 2nd table, only 1 row is displayed and the 2nd row is displayed in the first table. Not sure why.

Comment: Uhm... a little confusing (maybe because of late evening I can't think normally). Could you provide me some dummy data (`var_dump($_POST['rows'];`) so that I could check myself?

Comment: Would you be able to use some of the code that I have posted in my question because I know the problem would be somewhere in there.

Comment: Why not? :) Just need some dummy data to be able to see results on page.

Comment: I guess I am a bit confused haha sorry...never done anything with dummy data or worked with it or used it so not sure what to provide you with sorry :(

Answer (score 1):

In your js you do this:

```
var x=document.getElementById('tables1');
```

but in your html, you do not give your tables individual ids:

```
<table cellspacing="20">
```

Try

```
<table id="tables1" cellspacing="20">
```

and so on. All three tables need different id.

Comment: I fixed that and still get the same result